# Checbox not updating state in react

Tags: reactjs

So, i am making a page with some products and i need to filter them. If the user clicks on the checkbox it will only show products with that option checked. My problem is that when i check the checkbox it will filter the products as i want but when i set the current poducts it won't check.

```js
const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false)
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]) //I later set this from the api
const [currentProducts, setCurrentProducts] = useState([]) //the current products
const [selectedCultures, setSelecteedCultures] = useState([]) //Current active filters

...

function Filters() {

        return (
            <div>
                {
                    filterOptions.cultures.map(culture => {

                        const cultureID = culture.id
                        const cultureName = culture.name
                        const subcultures = culture.subcultures
                        const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)


                        function selectCulture(isChecboxChecked) {

                            setIsChecked(isChecboxChecked)
                            
                            if(isChecboxChecked){

                                const temp = selectedCultures
                                temp.push(cultureID)

                                setSelectedCultures(temp)
                            }
                            else{

                                const temp = removeItemFromFilter(cultureID, selectedCultures)
                            
                                setSelectedCultures(temp)
                            }

                            filterProducts()
                        }

                        return (

                            <div key={cultureID}>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col-12">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={event => selectCulture(event.target.checked)}></input>
                                        {" " + cultureName}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="row">
                                    {
                                        subcultures.map(subculture => {

                                            const subcultureID = subculture.id
                                            const subcultureName = subculture.name

                                            return (
                                                <div className="col-12" style={{ marginLeft: 20 }} key={subcultureID} >
                                                    <input type="checkbox"></input>
                                                    {" " + subcultureName}
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )

    }

function filterProducts() {

        var filteredProductsList = []

        products.forEach(product => {

            const productCultures = product.cultures
            const productSubcultures = product.subcultures
            const productEnemyGroups = product.enemyGroups
            const productEnemies = product.enemies
            const productCategory = product.category
            const productSubstances = product.substances
            var isProductAvailable = true

            //If there are cultures selected
            if (selectedCultures.length > 0) {

                selectedCultures.forEach(selectedCulture => {

                    var productHasCulture = false
                    productCultures.forEach(productCulture => {
                        if (productCulture === selectedCulture) {
                            productHasCulture = true
                        }
                    })

                    if (!productHasCulture) isProductAvailable = false
                })
            }


            if (isProductAvailable) { filteredProductsList.push(product) }
        })

        setCurrentProducts([...filteredProductsList])
    }

return (

        <div>
            {
                showContent
                    ?
                    <>
                        <div>
                            <Navbar activePage="catalog" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="catalogPage container-fluid">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-lg-3 col-6">

                                </div>
                                <div className="col-lg-9 col-6 mt-5">
                                    <h2>Produtos</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row container-fluid">
                                <div className="col-lg-3 col-6">
                                    <div className="inputBox row">
                                        <input className="col-12 text-center" placeholder="Procurar produtos"></input>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-12">
                                            <Filters />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-lg-9 col-6">
                                    <Products />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </>
                    :
                    ""
            }
        </div>
    )
```

This is the end result. The first checkbox should be checked.

[image]

I can't see why it won't check. I am losing my marbles with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what my problem was. Everytime i updated the current products it would rerender the filters and by default they are unchecked. I had to save the checked value in filterOptions for example.